# How to only replace exact word in text using regex c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am currently using this code to replace exact match. However this does not work, it also removed where the words appear in other words.

Example:

```
string pattern = "(?i)(flo)";
jobTitle = Regex.Replace("Florist of Vinyl Flowers of flo abc", pattern, string.Empty);
```

This is making the string :

> orist of Vinyl owers

Which is wrong it should only remove flo from the string, and if I use :

```
string pattern = "(?i)\b(flo)\b";
```

It does not match however even if there is a complete word in there it wont match, nothing matches/

UPDATE :

The complete code runs like this:

```
splitter = wordToremoveTitle.Split('|');
if (splitter.Length > 0)
 {

  for (int t = 0; t < splitter.Length ; t++)
  {
  String pattern = @"(?i)\b(" + splitter[t] + ")\b";
  jobTitle = Regex.Replace(jobTitle, pattern, string.Empty);
  }
```

Comment: `\b` is a C# character literal for a backspace. You need to escape it again to `\\b`, or use a verbatim string: `string pattern = @"(?i)\b(flo)\b";`

Comment: @vcsjones i did , changing to  (?i)\\b(florist)\b  but this does not even move florist from the original string ....   
string pattern = @"(?i)\b(" + splitter[t] + ")\b";

Comment: jobTitle = jobTitle.Replace(" flo ", string.Empty);

Comment: @boo it needs to be case insensitive .

Comment: You did not do what @vcsjones told you to do; you need `string pattern = @"(?i)\b(" + splitter[t] + @")\b";`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you was so close, regex: `(?i)\bflo\b`

```
string pattern = @"(?i)\bflo\b";
jobTitle = Regex.Replace("Florist of Vinyl Flowers", pattern, string.Empty);
```

if word mean "Florist" and "Flowers" but not "flo" use this one `(?i)\b[^ ]*flo[^ ]*\b`

Comment: I have applied the exact statement still no luck

Comment: (?i)\\b[^ ]*florist[^ ]*\b  this does not remove , florist from the string ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out what "word" mean for you and than define it using regular expressions.

You may need to define bounds if they don't match "\b" category (i.e. @"[\s,.-$]+" "white-space characters, begin/end of string, punctuations"). You may need to make use of @\w+" - "word characters" category to include remaining portion of word after prefix if needed.

Reference - [Character classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx).

Sample taht should match words starting with "flo":

```
  string pattern = @"(?i)\b(flo\w+)\b";
```

Comment: I do not want to match words starting with flo , but match word flo and replace it , but do not replace flo from flowers.